# .htaccess rule slight help needed

Tags: javascript, html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have spent hours trying to get this rule right and I am really struggling. I have got so close but I can not get it right. Any help is more than welcome... Thank you #

Trying to remove unwanted segments in the URL. From this:

`https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/help/rss/legal/rss/comment-picture`

To this:

`https://example.com/comment-picture`

The segments are random in name and in quantity, this is the rules I have so far

`RewriteEngine on`

`` RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\^|~|`|<|>|,|%|\\|\{|\}|\[|\]|\|)/ [NC] ``

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

It almost works but I need the last segment to be left, this rule gives a new URL of

`The new url is https://example.com/
Test are stopped, a redirect will be made with status code 301`

What is needed to leave the final segment?

I am getting closer

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^https:.*?com|\/[\w+-]+$) ~gm [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^https:.*?com|\/(.*)[\w+-]+$(.*) $2 [R=301,L]`

Gives me

`https://example.com/index.php`

So selecting the wrong part of URL but getting closer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct answer and I wish I could take the credit for it but I can't

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php/module/action/param1/.*/(.*+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This Is the work of a genus, I asked him for advice after coming across a very nice tool he has created. [RewriteRule_Generator](https://donatstudios.com/RewriteRule_Generator)

Answer (score 1):

The code below will give the 2 string you are looking for.

```
(^https:.*?com|\/[\w+-]+$)
```

Comment: That give me exactly what im looking for but how do I use this in the rewrite rule? I tried and still get the new URL is ```The new url is https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/rss/templates/system/modules/note/themes/asset/static/js/geo/profile/static/js/jquery/rss/rss/blog/category/rss/b/rss/rss/rss[R=301,L]```

Comment: i don't know `javascript`, so unfortunately, I cannot help.

Comment: Its for Apache2.4 rewrite rule. Thank you for the regex though its perfect